How do I backup my Chrome passkeys?
How do I backup passkeys created in Chrome?
I want to backup passkeys created by Chrome so I can continue to login to web sites if I lose access to my Google Account.

Where are they stored?
How do I export them?
How do I import them?

Bonus Reading

Store passkeys in Windows
If you have Windows 10 or up, you can use passkeys. To store passkeys, you must set up Windows Hello. Windows Hello doesn’t currently support synchronization or backup, so passkeys are only saved to your computer. If your computer is lost or the operating system is reinstalled, you can’t recover your passkeys.
Manage passkeys in Windows

On your computer, open Chrome.
Select More > Passwords and autofill > Google Password Manager.
On the left, select Settings > Manage passkeys in your Chrome profile.

Tip: “Manage passkeys” only shows when one or more passkeys have been created.


I would just backup the entire Chrome user profile.

Or, for completeness, make a drive image, which backs up everything on the local drive should it fail.

@ramhound passkeys are not stored in the chromeprofile  They are stored on the TPM (where AFAIK they can not be exported from) and if youuse chrome then they are also stored with your account in the Google-cloud and I would really like to know if they can be exported from there. I did not yet find any information on this. And this is a big red flag for using passkeys for me.

@DrMoishe passkeys are also not stored on disk

@raudi - You are mistaken. PassKeys within Chrome are store within the Password Manager. I found an article by Google themselves that stated this. I am not going to link to the article due to the fact, for non-English readers, the article might make it seem that Chrome uses the TPM instead of Windows Hello. The article seamlingly states that passkeys are store in the Chrome Password Manager then oddly also talks about Windows Hello which does use the TPM.
